# How to find the last visited waypoint and the next waypoint to be visit for making a ping pong mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The ping pong it self is working but not as I wanted.

The rule for the ping pong as I want it to be should be :

The transform has reached a waypoint for example the transform has reached waypoint at index 0.
So the last waypoint in this case is the transform original start position and then the ping pong should be between the waypoint at index 0 and the transform original start position.

and if for example the transform has reached at waypoint index 4 then waypoint index 4 should be the end and waypoint index 5 should be start : The transform should first keep moving to waypoint index 5 and then from waypoint index 5 to move back to waypoint index 4 and forth to 5 and make nonstop ping pong between indexes 5 and 5.

The logic is that the transform should keep moving finish moving and reaching the next waypoint and then make ping pong from the reached next waypoint to the visited waypoint before.

Now when I'm pressing the P key the transform move back or "jump" change position to the visited waypoint and then moving to the next waypoint and then keep doing the ping pong. but this is not what I wanted.

I will add a very short video clip showing the behaviour as it is now if needed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> WayPoints;

    private int CurrentWayPoint = 0;
    private bool IsPatrolling = false;
    private bool pingPongEnabled = false;
    private Vector3 pingPongStart;
    private Vector3 pingPongEnd;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartPatrol();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ReversePatrolWayPoints();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PingPong();
        }
    }

    public void StartPatrol()
    {
        if (!IsPatrolling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Patrol());
        }
    }

    public void ReversePatrolWayPoints()
    {
        WayPoints.Reverse();
    }

    public void PingPong()
    {
        pingPongEnabled = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator Patrol()
    {
        if (WayPoints == null || WayPoints.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waypoints list is null or empty");
            yield break;
        }

        IsPatrolling = true;

        while (CurrentWayPoint < WayPoints.Count)
        {
            if (pingPongEnabled)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pingPongStart,
                    WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position,
                    Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));

                yield return null;
                continue;
            }

            float distanceToWayPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 1f);

            if (distanceToWayPoint <= 1f)
            {
                pingPongEnd = WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position;

                Debug.LogFormat("Reached Waypoint {0}", CurrentWayPoint);
                CurrentWayPoint++;
                if (CurrentWayPoint >= WayPoints.Count)
                {
                    CurrentWayPoint = 0;
                }
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        IsPatrolling = false;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well as you know current waypoint surely you can work out how to add last waypoint visited?

Comment: @BugFinder WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint - 1]

Comment: Wel that wont necessarily ping pong but it is a start.